# How can I take this tabular data and group the fields correctly?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, input

I have this table of input fields that a user will fill out. As you can see, there's two pairs of fields, four columns across and and a minimum of five rows in length with the ability to dynamically add more rows as necessary. I've been struggling with how to name the input fields so that they can be grouped together correctly when the form is submitted. I've tried different variations of rows, etc. but none is working quite right. I would like for each pair to be in an array together, i.e.

```
[0] -> drum - value
[0] -> size - value
[1] -> drum - value
[1] -> size - value
```

Here's the table as I have it now. Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

```
<table id="drumInformation">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="9"><p>D R U M I N F O R M A T I O N – Drum Number(s) / Liter(s) or Gallon(s) Used</p>

                <p> If some or all of your drum numbers fall in consecutive order, please feel free to use the
                    "series" method shown below to avoid typing each drum number individually and to save you valuable time.</p>

                <p>Example:<br/>
                    10001, 10002, 10003, 10004, 10005, 10006 or 10001 - 10006</p>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="labelRow">
            <td class="label">
                <label>Drum No.</label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label><span class="euro">Liters</span><span class="domestic">Gallons</span></label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label>Drum No.</label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label><span class="euro">Liters</span><span class="domestic">Gallons</span></label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label>Drum No.</label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label><span class="euro">Liters</span><span class="domestic">Gallons</span></label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label>Drum No.</label>
            </td>
            <td class="label">
                <label><span class="euro">Liters</span><span class="domestic">Gallons</span></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td class="remove"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td class="remove"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td class="remove"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td class="remove"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][drumNumber][]">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="row[][gallons][]">
            </td>
            <td class="remove"><img src="/forms/assets/img/Plus-32.png" class="addRow"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Why not put the array number in the name? This is can be incremented and decremented using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works changing the table row to look like this:

```
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input name="group[8][drumNumber]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[8][gallons]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[9][drumNumber]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[9][gallons]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[10][drumNumber]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[10][gallons]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[11][drumNumber]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="group[11][gallons]">
        </td>
        <td class="remove"></td>
    </tr>
```

There might be a cleaner solution but this one works. I'm not sure why I was stuck with putting row[] whatever in the front.